# Google Sheets 'Text' function & Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, text, google-sheets-formula

Is there  any way to use the 'TEXT' function in the Google sheets Conditional Formatting sidebar?

For example, if ten rows need to be formatted as currency, based on a text description value in column A -- can a custom formula be used to execute the 'consequence' of an IF/THEN... if a TRUE condition exists?

Desired Format Rules/ Custom Formula (since 'number formatting' is not a viable 'Conditional Formatting option):
Apply to range 1:1
=IF(a1="REVENUE", TEXT(a3,"$#,##0.00"))
(the flag in a1 will dictate the row formatting)

Trying to AVOID having to iterate through all rows using code (such as the sample below) and instead  check for the 'flag' column and apply the required formatting in the UI.

```
var ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1');
var values = ss.getRange('a1:a10').getValues();
values.forEach(row=>{if (Range=="REVENUE") {ss.getRange(r,1).setNumberFormat("$#,##0.00")}}....
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample google sheet link showing a before and after sheet demonstrating with sample data the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes you can... use if statement combined with Text function. That should work without any scripting??

Comment: PGSystemTester, the 'consequence' portion of  the IF/THEN (the THEN half) does  not seem  to be evaluated  in the Conditional Formatting Side-bar --- unless there is some syntax nuance on how the formula should be entered....? 
Alternatively, is  there a way to enter the IF/THEN as an array (outside of the Conditional Format side-bar), so that the desired 'format the whole row' is  achieved after a 'flag column' is  read/ yields a 'TRUE' condition.

Comment: CodeCamper, sample you req
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Ic0tqqSHcnfpjGpaDqJK8nFo0NChlae_-9a_qDOrnk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Conditional formatting cannot modify number formats. It can only mess with color, background, bold, italic, etc depending on cell content. Custom formula can help you only determine which cells should be formatted. You cannot use formula to determine HOW it should be formatted.

Comment: Can you provide access to your sheet?